# recursive return statement with || in it

Tags: java, android

the following method's return statement has stumped me:

```
public static boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target, int max) {

        if (start >= nums.length) { return target == 0; }
        // can't use max value
        else if (nums[start] == max) {
          return groupSum(start + 1, nums, target, max);
        }
        else {
            return groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start], max) ||
                   groupSum(start + 1, nums, target, max);
        }
      }
```

if you notice, the return statement has a || "or" clause in it, and I am confused as to which clause is being returned here... if you could provide an explanation on how this works, that would be great.

Comment: A `return` statement _returns_ a value, not a clause. The `||` is an operator that is applied to two operands and produces a value.

Comment: so which value gets returned? the value on the left side or right side ? and what is it based on ?

Comment: @user3730244 - The result is a comparison of the two operands, not any one of the operands

Comment: Do you know what the `||` operator does? That's what you should be researching.

Comment: You should draw the recursion tree.

Comment: how would i draw a recursion tree ?

Answer (score 4):

Since `||` is a so called short curcuit operator, the first expression is evaluated and if, and only if, it evaluates to true, true is returned immediately, without evaluating the second one. if it fails the second one is evaluated and it's result is returned.

So if you have

```
a() || b()
```

and a evaluates to true b() is not evaluated

Comment: what if a dose not evaluate to true, and neither does b ?

Comment: @user3730244 Then you get `false || false`. What does that mean?

Comment: i have no idea what false || false means... does the method just crash ?

Comment: In short circuit if the first is true you will not recurse to groupSum(start + 1, nums, target, max). Otherwise, if the first is false.. it's mandatory to recurse to check if it'll return true or false. If both are false, the evaluation return will be false.

Answer (score 2):

The `||` operator is not choosing which expression to return, it's performing a logical-OR between both expressions, and after that, `return` returns the result.

The `return` statement will return `true` if either of the expressions is `true`, and it will return `false` if both expressions are `false`.

Comment: @RichardTingle Meant one thing, typed another.  Corrected.